# GS1-128 ZPL generation with GTIN (01) with only 13 digits

Tags: barcode, zpl, gs1-128

I'd like to generate a GS1-128 barcode like this

```
    (01)5410413901026(17)170612(10)LOT100
```

in ZPL code

```
    ^BY5,3,160^FT372,1506^BCB,,N,N,N
    ^FD>;>8015410413901026>817170612>810>6LOT100^FS
```

My problem is the 01 code is normally exactly 14 digits, here my EAN is only 13 digits. So my barcode is misformed.

I have already tried to put `>8` at the begin of every new AI without result.

Answer (score 1):

EAN is always 13 digits. Add a leading zero to convert to a 14-digit GTIN. (A digit other than 0 at the start identifies a wholesale container of the item.)

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56673316/323917

Parentheses and spaces can be in the field data. '00' application identifier, followed by 17 characters, followed by bogus check digit place holder.

[image]

Ref: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

I have verified the barcode from https://zxing.org/w/decode and https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/