# How to create a GS1-128 barcode using ZPL with a check digit

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, zpl, gs1-128

I need to generate a GS1-128 barcode using ZPL.  It needs to include a check digit.  I do not seem to get the check digit.

```
Here is my code:
^BCN,088,Y,Y,Y,D^FD(00)00123456000057763^FS

The first "Y"  is saying to print the human readable along with the 
barcode.  The third "Y" is supposed to tell it to include a check digit.  
I'm not seeing the check digit in the human readable, my scanner is not 
displaying a check digit, so I'm assuming it is also not in the barcode?  


Here is from the spec:
SSCC Barcode Structure (20 digits) 
Application Identifier = (00) 
Positions of SSCC barcode: 
 1 = Extension Digit (0-9 assigned by Vendor) 
 2 = 0 if mfg id # assigned by GS1 US; 
 1-9 if mfg id # assigned by another GS1 MO 
 3 thru 8 = 6-digit mfg id # 
 9 thru 17 = 9-digit serial id # -must be unique for one year
 18 = Modulo 10 check character
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; 
`^BCN,088,Y,Y,,D`
`^FD(00)001234560000577630^FS`

The third Y does include a Checkdigit, but not the one you want (ZPL Manual, p73):

> Mod 103 check digit is always there. It cannot be turned on or off. Mod 10 and 103 appear together with [the third Y] turned on.

When you use `D`, it will automatically add a checkdigit(ZPL Manual, p80):

> The printer automatically
>   determines if a check digit is required, calculate it, and print it.

But more importantly, it expects you to send 18 digits :

> Parentheses and spaces can be in the field data. '00' application identifier, followed
>   by 17 characters, followed by bogus check digit place holder.

It'll strip out the 18th digit and replace it in both the barcode and the human readable part.

https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much!  This seems to have worked - I appreciate the help